# Is it possible to create with a loop a program that creates 1000 files in a folder? Each file should have the progressive number

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried with this example but I know it is stupid, so I ask to someone a tip, thanks in advance

```
for i in range(1000):
file=open(r"C:\Users\PC\Desktop\LOL\"file"+str(i)."txt","w")
file.write("Hello")
```

Comment: All you have wrong here is one quote too many, and a `.` where you should use `+`.

Comment: The answer to your question is, trivially: yes. If there is an error in your code, you should provide full traceback.

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in range(1000):
    file=open(r"C:\Users\PC\Desktop\LOL\file{}.txt".format(i),"w")
    file.write("Hello")
    file.close()
```

should do the trick. Or alternatively with a [context manager](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement):

```
for i in range(1000):
    with open(r"C:\Users\PC\Desktop\LOL\file{}.txt".format(i),"w") as fh:
        fh.write('Hello')
```

You should also avoid using the variable name `file` as it shadows the built in function.

Comment: Note that in Python 3.x, `file` is no longer a builtin function - so there's nothing to shadow...

Comment: It would probably still be best to avoid it for the sake of backwards compatibility; at least until 2.x usage drops.